# How to use dynamic variables from WordPress/Timber in Twig macros

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twig, timber

I am in the process of writing a Twig macro for call to action links on my client's website. The following code shows what I have so far and where am I having issues with using double curly braces inside of the macro instances.

**Macro cta.twig code**

```
{% macro pill(options={}) %}
  {% set options = {
    class: "",
    link: "",
    title: "",
    text: ""
  } | merge(options) %}
  <a class="cta {{ options.class }}" href="{{ options.link }}" title="{{ options.title }}">{{ options.text }}
    <span>
      <svg role="img" class="arrow arrow--right" width="22" height="18">
        <path d="M9.267 1.206L10.3.29a1.216 1.216 0 0 1 1.577 0l9.046 8.008c.437.388.437 1.014 0 1.398l-9.046 8.012a1.216 1.216 0 0 1-1.577 0l-1.033-.915c-.442-.391-.433-1.03.018-1.413l5.607-4.732H1.52c-.619 0-1.117-.441-1.117-.99V8.341c0-.549.498-.99 1.117-.99h13.373L9.285 2.62c-.456-.383-.465-1.022-.018-1.413z" fill="#FFF"/>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </a>
{% endmacro %}
```

**Macro used in _html.twig template**

```
{{ cta.pill({
  class: "cta--pill cta--no-shadow",
  link: "{{ post.link }}",
  title: "{{ __('View all services', howellsexcavating) }}",
  text: "{{ post.meta( 'module_more_button_text' ) }}"
}) }}
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<a class="cta cta--pill cta--no-shadow" href="{{ post.link }}" title="{{ __('View all services', howellsexcavating) }}">
  {{ post.meta( 'module_more_button_text' ) }}
  <span>
    <svg role="img" class="arrow arrow--right" width="22" height="18">
        <path d="M9.267 1.206L10.3.29a1.216 1.216 0 0 1 1.577 0l9.046 8.008c.437.388.437 1.014 0 1.398l-9.046 8.012a1.216 1.216 0 0 1-1.577 0l-1.033-.915c-.442-.391-.433-1.03.018-1.413l5.607-4.732H1.52c-.619 0-1.117-.441-1.117-.99V8.341c0-.549.498-.99 1.117-.99h13.373L9.285 2.62c-.456-.383-.465-1.022-.018-1.413z" fill="#FFF"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</a>
```

As you can see the plain text is properly rendered in the class attribute, but anything in curly braces that is dynamic from WordPress and Timber is not.

Is it possible to use curly brace wrapped dynamic variables and functions in Twig macros, or should I be taking a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotes and curly brackets from options object - this way it is considered as a string. Use it like

```
{{ cta.pill({
  class: "cta--pill cta--no-shadow", // this requires to be string so keep it as it is
  link: post.link, // this is dynamic variable - do NOT use quotes 
  title: __('View all services', 'howellsexcavating'),
  text: post.meta( 'module_more_button_text' )
}) }}
```